# How to render multiple H1 tags in a for loop with Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a table and I want to print each item in the table and print it in Shiny, how do I do it in a for loop?

My desired outcome is to print 1, 2, 3, ..., until 100.

Thanks in advance!

See the following minimal example, if I use for loop in renderUI, it just couldn't render the H1 tags. I guess the problems is that for loop is not allowed in renderUI.

```
  library(shiny)

  ui <- fluidPage(

      fluidPage(

        uiOutput("ui_main_articles_area")

      )
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

      table <- reactive({

          table <- data.frame(Item = 1:100)

          return(table)

      })

      output$ui_main_articles_area <- renderUI({

          fluidPage(

              # for (i in 1:nrow(table())) {
              #
              #     #this doesn't work
              #
              #     tags$h1(table()[i, "Item"])
              #
              # }

              #the following is my desired outcome, I want to print from 1 to 100 without writing it one by one

              tags$h1(table()[1, "Item"]),

              tags$h1(table()[2, "Item"]),

              tags$h1(table()[3, "Item"]),

          )

      })

  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidPage(
    uiOutput("ui_main_articles_area")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 table <- reactive({
    data.frame(Item = 1:100)
  })
  
  output$ui_main_articles_area <- renderUI({
    items <-table()$Item
    tags_list <- lapply(items, function(item) {
      tags$h1(item)
    })
    
    do.call(tagList, tags_list)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a for loop:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(fluidPage(uiOutput("ui_main_articles_area")))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  table <- reactive({
    table <- data.frame(Item = 1:100)
    
    return(table)
    
  })
  
  output$ui_main_articles_area <- renderUI({
    ui_elements <- tagList()
    
    for (i in 1:nrow(table())) {
      ui_elements <- tagList(ui_elements, tags$h1(table()[i, "Item"]))
    }
    
    fluidPage(ui_elements)
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```